# PHP code blocking site content from loading

Tags: php, sql, function, block

I am having issues with the following code. It just blocks the rest of the site to load and it does not do it´s intended function.

There is a JS before the main PHP, which looks as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //http://jsbin.com/ujuse/1/edit
$(function() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {
        var boxes = [];
        // You could save a little time and space by doing this:
        var name = this.name;
        // critical change on next line
        $("input[type='checkbox'][name='"+this.name+"']:checked").each(function() {
            boxes.push(this.value);
        });
        if (boxes.length) {
            $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300);
            // Change the name here as well
            $(".indexMain").load('store/indexMain.php?'+this.name+'=' + boxes.join("+"),
            function() {
                $(".indexMain").fadeIn('slow');
                $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300);
            });

        } else {
            $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300);
            $(".indexMain").load('store/indexMain.php', function() {
                $(".indexMain").fadeIn('slow');
                $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

---

```
<?php
function echoCheckboxSet($con, $header, $divClass, $columnName, $setName) {
$checkboxes = $con -> prepare("SELECT DISTINCT $columnName FROM item_descr ORDER BY $columnName ASC");
$checkboxes->execute();
?>
<div class="bgFilterTitles">
    <h1 class="filterTitles"><?php echo $header;?></h1>
</div>
<div class="<?php echo $divClass; ?>">
<?php
    while ($box = $checkboxes->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
    $boxColumnName = str_replace('_',' ',$box[$columnName]);
?>
        <input type='checkbox' class='regularCheckbox' name='<?php echo $setName; ?>' value='<?php echo $box[$columnName]; ?>' />
        <font class='similarItemsText'><?php echo $boxColumnName; ?></font>
        <br />
<?php
endwhile;
?>
</div>
<?php
} // end of echoCheckboxSet

// Call our method twice, once for colors and once for prices
echoCheckBoxSet("COLOR", "colors", "color_base1", "color");
echoCheckBoxSet("PRICE", "prices", "price", "price");
?>
```

---

```
    Warning: Missing argument 5 for echoCheckboxSet(), called in 
\store\indexLeftBar.php on line 58 and defined in \store\indexLeftBar.php on line 35

    Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in \store\indexLeftBar.php on line 36
```

Do you see any issue?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Like John asked, without knowing the steps you've done to show us where the problem MIGHT be this is really hard to answer for you.  Trying doing some print statements to follow the flow of your code execution.  Saying "nothing is happening" doesnt help us.

Comment: This code was working before I placed the php file that runs it into a subfolder of my parent directory. There is a Javascript running before this, it was also working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$con` is used, but not in scope:

```
function echoCheckboxSet($header, $divClass, $columnName, $setName) {
    $checkboxes = $con->....
}
```

Either pass it in as an argument (shown below) to the function, or declare it as `global` (the latter is not recommended).

```
function echoCheckboxSet($con, $header, $divClass, $columnName, $setName) {
    $checkboxes = $con->....
}

$con = some_method_that_connects_to_your_db(); // <!-- Still need this
echoCheckBoxSet( $con, "COLOR", "colors", "color_base1", "color");
```

Comment: How should I pass it as an argument?

Comment: I see no reason why my original code would not work. I think your answer does not address the issue

Comment: @samyb8 - If you see no reason why it wouldn't work, then why doesn't it work? I've already explained at least what is for sure one of your problems. Nobody else can discern anything more without A) more details and B) an error message, two things your question is lacking.

Comment: I agree, sorry I didn't add the error comment... I just updated the question with the error I get after adding the $con to the function's arguments

Comment: @samy - You need to connect to your database somehow. I added a comment on the line in my answer that you're still missing. Then, you need to change how you're calling the function, from `echoCheckBoxSet("PRICE", "prices", "price", "price");` to `echoCheckBoxSet( $con, "PRICE", "prices", "price", "price");`. So, `$con` must be created so you connect to your database (with `new PDO()` or `new mysqli()` or however you connect to your database), then you have to pass `$con` to the function.